# divergence in cylindrical coordinates explanation

Tags: vector-analysis

I was looking at the formula for divergence in cylindrical system and couldn't quite understand the existence of a certain term . So the divergence in cylindrical system is gives as

$\nabla .\vec A = \dfrac{\partial Ap}{\partial p} + \dfrac {Ap} {p} + \dfrac{1}{p}\dfrac{\partial{A\theta}}{\partial{\theta}}+\dfrac{\partial Az}{\partial z}$

Existence of all the terms are self-explanatory except $\dfrac{Ap}{p}$ . Why is that term needed . I know it arrives during the derivation but what is the meaning of that term ?

Thank you

Comment: This is the best intuition I have seen for this kind of thing, it only involves geometry but you do have to accept that dividing by an infinitesimal means taking a derivative: https://copaseticflow.blogspot.com/2012/09/an-intuitive-way-to-spherical-gradient.html

Answer (score 1):

$A_{\rho}$ is the component of $A$ along $\hat{\rho}$. So the term $\frac{A_{\rho}}{\rho}$ is simply that component over $\rho$.

If you understand the derivation, you understand that that term is needed. If you want the divergence in only three terms, you have

$$\nabla \cdot A=\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial (\rho A_{\rho})}{\partial \rho}+\frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial A_{\theta}}{\partial \theta}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}$$

Comment: but doesn't $\dfrac{\partial{Ap}}{\partial{p}}}$ already define the growth of Ap with respect to 'p' . Why is the additional term needed . I expressed it in four terms cause I thought the 3-term expression was even more confusing.

Comment: @Harrison Apparently not, since the derivation requires it. I know you want some intuition for why that is, but cylindrical and spherical (and other non-Cartesian) coordinate systems don't behave in the nice and linear ways that we are used to, and which we have built our intuition around.